# How to separate long string into a string array with IFS and read, or any other method

Tags: bash, read, bash-array

I have a long line that comes as output from a git command: `a=$(git submodule foreach git status)`. It looks like this:
a = "Entering '**Dir1/Subdir**' On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working tree clean Entering '**Dir2**' HEAD detached at xxxxxx nothing to commit, working tree clean Entering '**Dir3**' On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working tree clean Entering '**Dir4**' On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'. nothing to commit, working tree clean"

I want to separate it into an array:

ARR[0] = "'**Dir1/Subdir**' On branch master ..."

ARR[1] = "'**Dir2**' HEAD detached at ..."

etc.

To do that, I have tried to substitute "Entering " for a symbol (I have tried # $ % & \t ...) with `a=${a//Entering /$}` and it works alright. Then, I try to use IFS and read to separate it into an array: `IFS='$' read -ra ARR <<< "$a"`

It's here where I am facing problems.

The output that I get of `echo ${ARR[@]}` is "Dir1/Subdir1" so I think that read is being affected by spaces or by how the output from git is, but I don't understand what is happening and how to fix it. Could you please give me any suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `readarray` bash builtin and specify the delimiter within the same command:

```bash
readarray -d 'char delimiter' array <<< $variable
```

For example:

```bash
readarray -d '@' array <<< ${a//Entering /@}
```

Finally when you print each result you might want to remove the `@` (or any other character used as delimiter):

```bash
echo ${array[1]%@}
echo ${array[2]%@}
echo ${array[@]%@}
```

If you want to delete the index `0` (because it contains `@`) you can reassign the array by copying the items from index `1` to last index:

```bash
array=("${array[@]:1}")
```

**Tip:** If you want to avoid use `${array[index]%@}` each time you want to get some item, you can reassign the array again by removing the `@` with:

```bash
array=("${array[@]/@}")
```

Comment: This worked really well!

The only problem I had was to get rid of the first element, but I will just unset it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zaida glad that worked for you. I updated my answer to provide a possible solution to remove the index `0` and avoid use bash parameter expansion.

Comment: Hi Edgar, the removal of index `0` worked flawlessly, but the removal of the delimiter worked with `@` as delimiter but not with `%`. Do you know what could be happening?

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that `%` is a symbol used for string manipulation, so using `array=("${array[@]/'%'}")` was enough to make it work. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Zaida great you have solved ! About your question about what is happening I think it's because the `bash parameter expansion` uses special characters like `%` (e.g.  `echo ${array[1]%@}`) or `#` to apply pattern and get a result. See [this article](https://datacadamia.com/lang/bash/parameter_expansion) or you can use `man bash`

Comment: Another possible solution is using `array=("${array[@]//%}")`. I'm not really sure if this code and your do exactly the same but both work.